# UITextView with NSAttributedString and custom attributes not working

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview, nsattributedstring

When using a UITextView I try to add a custom attribute to an attributed string. However, all custom keys are lost after assigning to a UITextView's attributedText. Like this:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *lString = [[ NSMutableAttributedString alloc ] initWithString: @"astring"
                                             attributes: @{ @"customkey": @"customvalue" }];
NSLog(@"string: %@", lString);  // shows customkey present
textView.attributedText = lString;
NSLog(@"result: %@", self.textView.attributedText);   // shows customkey missing
```

Is this supposed to work?

Comment: What custom attribute(s) are you using? I don't see how `UITextView` could know how to render custom attributes. You need to use one of the documented attributes.

Comment: Custom attributes. If I use the documented attributes it works. It could now know about them but keep them instead of discard them, right?

Comment: Can you explain how you expect `UITextView` to know anything about your custom attributes? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to add "astring" in the UITextField, and keep information about "astring" around, like that "customkey" is set to "customvalue", even if the user adds characters before "astring", after "astring", or changes "astring" to "foobar". All I want is for UITextView not to forget customkey like it would not forget the font it was set in if a user typed other things around it or changed the word. It does not have to render or do anything else with it, just keep it around.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me in iOS 7. @KristofVanLandschoot do you still have this issue?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Starting with iOS 7, it now works as you'd like:

From [Accessing Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Tasks/AccessingAttrs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000161-BAJBBCBI):

> An attributed string identifies attributes by name, storing a value under the attribute name in an NSDictionary object, which is in turn associated with an NSRange that indicates the characters to which the dictionary’s attributes apply. **You can assign any attribute name-value pair you wish to a range of characters, in addition to the standard attributes.**

It works with both standard and `NSTextStorage` (Text Kit) backed UITextViews.

Comment: Sounds like it's what I needed. I've not been working on that part of the code anymore. A good reason to adopt iOS 7 and check it out!

Answer (score 6):

Based on the comments, you are trying to misuse `NSAttributedString`.`NSAttributedString` and `UITextView` are only designed to handle the documented attributes. You may be able to initially store custom attributes in the string, but once the text view starts processing the attributed text and you ask the text view for the latest attributed text, the text view will have long gotten rid of any custom attributes.

The better solution would be to create a class that extends UITextView. Your subclass should add a property that can hold whatever custom attributes you want. Or maybe your custom class would override the `attributedText` and 'setAttributedText:` methods. These would take care of saving off and restoring any custom attributes found in the attributed string.

Note: **this answer applies to iOS 6 and earlier**.
For iOS 7 see @julien_c's answer below.

Comment: OK. So it's not supposed to work. This is not in Apple's official documentation anywhere, right?

Comment: The documentation doesn't claim to support custom attributes. The documentation talks about the keys it does support. Unless the docs specifically state that something is supported, you must assume that it isn't supported. There is no way to document things that are not supported. There isn't a storage device on Earth big enough to document what isn't supported. :)

Comment: Just that to me this sounds like sound reasoning: UITextView supports attributed strings and attributed strings support custom keys so UITextView will work with attributed strings that have custom keys. Some warning in the documentation would have been welcome.

But I get your point :)

Comment: It does imply it quite strongly

"An attributed string identifies attributes by name, using an NSDictionary object to store a value under the given name. You can assign any attribute name/value pair you wish to a range of characters—it is up to your application to interpret custom attributes (see Attributed String Programming Guide)."

Apple's UIKit controls don't seem to keep custom attributes around though. It would be nice.

Comment: I am bolding text with `NSMutableAttributedString` by changing the typeface and would like to display it in a `UITextView`, but it gives me a warning saying "Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSString *' from 'NSMutableAttributedString *'." Do you know what I am doing wrong, because as far as I can tell, I am using one of Apple's official attributes?

Comment: This accepted answer is outdated, because as the answer below says iOS 7 accepts custom attributes.

Comment: @fatuhoku Things change over time. Leaving your comment for future readers is fine. There is nothing wrong with pointing out that the answer is now obsolete. But do not down vote an answer that was correct when it was answered. Otherwise you could spend the rest of your life down voting obsolete answers due to changing APIs and functionality. You can't expect people to go back and update all of their answers every time there is an API update.

Comment: Point taken. Sorry I downvoted.
I consulted http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down and I agree with you.

However my downvote has been locked now. What I'll do is edit the answer to make it explicit that it applies to iOS 6 and earlier.

Answer (score 3):

UITextView does not really display attributed strings. Apple has an internal class NSHTMLWriter which converts the set NSAttributedString into HTML data which is then displayed by the content UIWebDocumentView (which is essentially Webkit)

See my analysis here: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/12/uitextview-caught-with-trousers-down/

Comment: This is no longer true since `UITextView` is backed by TextKit not WebKit now, right?

Comment: @Suragch yes, I believe since iOS 8 it displays actual attributed strings.