# UITextView, NSAttributedString and custom attributes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have searched a lot on Stack Overflow but I couldn't find a solution. Perhaps I just misinterpreted some answers.

I have created a `UITextView` and I am using `NSAttributedStrings` to work with the UITextView which is just fine.

Now, after adding a custom attribute, I am stuck.

Where can I hook in to render my custom attribute within the `UITextView`? Is there a delegate method, or will I have to create my own `UITextView` and overwrite a method?

Comment: FWIW, You can see the complete list of UITextView delegate methods [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/)

Comment: not getting your question properly! do you want to set set atrributed string to your textview?

Comment: @KetanParmar No, he is already doing that. He has created a custom Attribute for the attributed string. He is wondering how can he render that in his textview

Comment: Relevant: [UITextView - NSAttributedString and CustomAttributes not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648003/uitextview-with-nsattributedstring-and-custom-attributes-not-working)

Comment: Exactly. Adding a custom attribute is no magic ;).. I just don't have a clue to get the UITextView to render this, or more specific: where must I implement my render code for the custom attribute

Comment: To "render", you need to go with CoreText.

Comment: That's not exactly what I need. I know I have to deal with CoreText, that's not the problem. But where must place my custom code to render my custom attribute? Where is it called from the UITextView?

Answer (score 8):

You can custom `NSLayoutManager`, and implement it's `-drawGlyphsForGlyphRange:atPoint:` method.

For example, you want a custom background with a corner radius

textView init:

```
NSTextStorage *textStorage = [NSTextStorage new];
CustomLayoutManager *layoutManager = [[CustomLayoutManager alloc] init];
CGSize containerSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width,  CGFLOAT_MAX);
NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:containerSize];

textContainer.widthTracksTextView = YES;
[layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];
[textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];

self.textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:yourFrame textContainer:textContainer];
```

And apply your custom attribute:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *mAttrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"SampleText"];
[mAttrStr addAttribute:YourCustomAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, mAttrStr.length)];  //for example, you want a custom background with a corner radius
[self.textView.textStorage appendAttributedString:mAttrStr];
```

In CustomLayoutManager.m

```
-(void)drawGlyphsForGlyphRange:(NSRange)glyphsToShow atPoint:(CGPoint)origin {
    NSRange range = [self characterRangeForGlyphRange:glyphsToShow
                                 actualGlyphRange:NULL];
    //enumerate custom attribute in the range
    [self.textStorage enumerateAttribute:YourCustomAttributeName inRange:range options:NSAttributedStringEnumerationLongestEffectiveRangeNotRequired usingBlock:^(id  _Nullable value, NSRange range, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        if (value) {
            UIColor *color = value; //the color set above

            NSRange glyphRange = [self glyphRangeForCharacterRange:range
                                          actualCharacterRange:NULL];
            NSTextContainer *container = [self textContainerForGlyphAtIndex:glyphRange.location
                                        effectiveRange:NULL];

            //draw background
            CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            CGContextSaveGState(context);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, origin.x, origin.y);
            [color setFill];
            CGRect rect = [self boundingRectForGlyphRange:glyphRange inTextContainer:container];

            //UIBezierPath with rounded
            UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect cornerRadius:100];
            [path fill];
            CGContextRestoreGState(context);
            //end draw

            [super drawGlyphsForGlyphRange:range atPoint:origin];
        }
        else {
            [super drawGlyphsForGlyphRange:range atPoint:origin];
        }

    }];
}
```

Now the 'SampleText' has a red rounded background.

Comment: I've tried your example, but unfortunately the drawGlyphsForGlyphRange:atPoint: is never called.

Comment: You need use `[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:rect textContainer:textStorage]` to init your textView.

Comment: Interestingly, if the attributed string contains emoji, the layout manager will break the string on the emoji character and will call `enumerateAttribute` for each substring, i.e. `helloworld` -> `hello`, ``, `world`

Comment: The solution to the emoji problem is to remove `options: NSAttributedString.EnumerationOptions.longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired`

Answer (score -1):

Please refer this simple code snippet to set attributed string to a textview

```
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"Test string to add attributes")
    attributedString.addAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.greenColor()], range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.string.characters.count))
    textView.attributedText = attributedString
```

For Objective-C

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"Test string to add attributes"];
[attributedString addAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor greenColor]} range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.string.length)];
textView.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: He is already doing that. Read the question before answering and ask for clarification if in doubt. Also the question is about Objective C, not swift. Again, Read the question

Comment: I don't see how the question is exclusively about Objective C but I upvoted nishith's answer because it helped me with Swift

Answer (score -1):

If you want apply particular `attributes` for particular `textView` rather then string then you should subclass `UITextView` and make custom `initmethod` or some method that return `UITextView` object with specified attribute!! You can pass `custom attributes` as parameter in method also if attributes are change i mean not fix. and if attribute will remain same implicitly then set attributes in that class by default.